# In Jquery how to get the id of first child, here I am talking about Jquery Treeview

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

My Treeview looks like this: its haml

## submission_database

```
          = @users.each do |user|
            %ul
              %li
                = link_to user.name, #
                = user.databases.each do |database|
                  %ul{:class => "database_user"}
                    %li{:id => database.id} 
                      = link_to database.title + " ("+database.database_versions.length.to_s + " Versions  )", # 
                      = database.database_versions.each do |version|
                        %ul{:class => "database_versions"}
                          %li{:id => version.id}
                            = link_to version.created_at
```

$('.database_user li a').click(function(s){

alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));

return false;

});

But my alert shows undefined !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
$('.database_user li a').click(function(s){
    alert($("li:first",$(this).siblings("ul.database_versions")).attr("id");
}
```

Comment: How to expand the top most node (very first node) of the tree on page load ?

Comment: you can trigger an click event to that. `$(document).ready(function(){$("first node selector").trigger("click");});`

Comment: That was precisely my question, how would I get the "first node selector" at run time for a dynamically generated tree

Comment: but you didn't ask precisely what you want. it's like yelling "coffee!" and wanting a two sugar expresso without cream. Try using developer tools or firebug to get it's id or class etc.

Comment: I completely agree that my question wasn't precise, the class of the top most node would be: "database_user". Now I wanna get the id of the top most node - ideally it belongs to this class

Comment: ".database_user:first" may work there. or ".database_user:first li:first"

Comment: $(".database_user:first li:first").trigger("click") or this $(".database_user:first").trigger("click") does not seem to work. I have used them right inside - $(document).ready(function() {}